# Need help on google sheet conditional formatting

Tags: conditional-formatting

Currently I have

```
=N1:N200<=SMALL($N$1:$N$200,15)
```

for finding the smallest 15 numbers from N1 to N200. It works except it includes all the 0s. How can I skip the 0s?